# best workflow in python data simulation : arrays VS dictionaries VS dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm simulating tournaments, and at the moment, everything seems very slow to me.

So I have 4 classes : *match* (1vs1) , *round* (2^n players), *tournament* (rounds from 2^n player until end), and *simulation* (where I simulate 100 tournament)

At the moment, *simulation* calls multiple *tournament*, which calls multiple *rounds*, which calls multiple *matches*.

*Matches* return one line dataframes (with players names, players ELO -it's chess-, players scores, match outcome, etc) to *round* (round append each oh this dataframes to his own empty dataframe).

*Round* return  2^(n-1) lines dataframes to *tournament* (tournament append each oh this dataframes to his own empty dataframe)

And *simulation* append each of the tournament dataframes to his own empty dataframe

Should I instead return numpy arrays and at the very last step, convert everything to a dataframe ? Or should I use dictionaries ?

Every help is welcome
thank you

Comment: Hi there! welcome to stack overflow :) please see this guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). specifically, code asking specific questions with code examples/bug logs are likely to get good answers, but open-ended questions with few concrete details are likely to be downvoted or closed

Comment: Without knowing more about your specific use case/code, it's hard to know for sure what's slowing it down, but in general pandas and numpy are best at scale, and using them to manage operations for a few numbers at a time is unlikely to out-perform dictionaries and simple math.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thank you for your response. Should I have posted some code ? (It's so many lines, that I thought I should try to explain the general Idea)

Comment: if the code is a large number of lines, then it's probably not pandas/numpy that are the performance problem. Check out this guide to [timing and profiling from real python](https://realpython.com/python-timer/) for some tips on diagnosing performance bottlenecks.

Comment: but in general, yeah the best answers will come if you have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). try to boil your code down to the smallest possible example which produces the question, then ask about that.